# Illegal modifier for parameter onOptionsItemSelected method

Tags: java, android

I am having an error message with the code i have wrote. Everything should be okay,because the examples are with the same code ,but somehow im getting an error. The error message says:

> Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
>     - Illegal modifier for parameter onOptionsItemSelected; only final is    permitted
>     - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected

```java
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
        awesome.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menuSweet:
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.startandroidkj.SWEET"));
                return true;
            case R.id.menuToast:
                Toast andEggs =Toast.makeText(menu.this,"this is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                andEggs.show();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot have a nested method in Java. Basically, the compiler thinks that you are defining a local variable and complains about its modifiers.

All you need to do, is add the missing closing brace of onCreateOptionsMenu() after the fourth line of code.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu)
{
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater awesome=getMenuInflater();
    awesome.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
} // <----------------------- Missing closing brace
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menuSweet:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.startandroidkj.SWEET"));
            return true;
        case R.id.menuToast:
            Toast andEggs =Toast.makeText(menu.this,"this is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            andEggs.show();
            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
```

It would help a lot if you format your code properly. Your indentation is messed up, and that makes it harder to find such mistakes.

Comment: It is  mis-formatting. Any idea how to get the code working ?

Comment: Just un-nest the methods from one another. I will type in the solution.

Comment: Lol, what a stupid mistake from me,but thanks alot !